# Retrieve many to many relation with laravel eloquent

Tags: mysql, php-7, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to retrieve data from many to many relation grouped in one object for the duplicated date.

I have menu table and daily_mealz table and pivot table(menu_daily_mealz)
the problem is the daily_mealz contain duplicated date value in its date column but every raw contain different meal_id.

So, I need to retrieve one raw but contain all mealsIDs related to this date

I only retrieve with belongsTo relation and them for loop over the data to get the object I need.

**Relations**

```
public function dailyMeals(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(DailyMeals::class, 'menu_daily_meals', 'menu_id', 'daily_meal_id');
}
public function menus(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Menu::class, 'menu_daily_meals', 'daily_meal_id', 'menu_id');
}
```

**DataBase Structure**

Menu table

```
+-----+----------------+
| id  | name           |
+-----+----------------+
| 1   | first menu     |
| 2   | second menu    |
+-----+----------------+
```

daily mealz table

```
+----+-------------+---------+-------+
| id | date        | meal_id | stock |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+
| 1  | 2019-03-01  |    1    | 250   |
|    |             |         |       |
| 2  | 2019-03-01  |    2    | 100   |
|    |             |         |       |
| 3  | 2019-03-02  |    3    | 150   |
|    |             |         |       |
| 4  | 2019-03-02  |    4    | 70    |
|    |             |         |       |
| 5  | 2019-03-03  |    5    | 350   |
|    |             |         |       |
| 6  | 2019-03-03  |    6    | 180   |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+
```

Menu_daily_meals table

```
+----+---------+---------------+
| id | menu_id | daily_meal_id |                               
+----+---------+---------------+
| 1  |       1 |     1         |
| 2  |       1 |     2         |
| 3  |       1 |     3         |
| 4  |       1 |     4         |
| 5  |       1 |     5         |
| 6  |       1 |     6         |
| 7  |       2 |     3         |
| 8  |       2 |     5         |
| 9  |       2 |     6         |
+----+---------+---------------+
```

**I need to retrieve object like that**

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "first menu",
  "daily_meals": [
    {
       "id": 1,
       "daily_date": "2019-03-01",
       "meals" : [
              {
                "meal_id" : 1,
                "stock"   : 250
              },
              {
                "meal_id" : 2,
                "stock"   : 100
              },
          ]
    },
    {
       "id": 2,
       "daily_date": "2019-03-02",
       "meals" : [
              {
                "meal_id" : 3,
                "stock"   : 150
              },
              {
                "meal_id" : 4,
                "stock"   : 70
              },
          ]
    },
    {
       "id": 3,
       "daily_date": "2019-03-03",
       "meals" : [
              {
                "meal_id" : 5,
                "stock"   : 350
              },
              {
                "meal_id" : 6,
                "stock"   : 180
              },
          ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Any Help, Please?**

Answer (score 0):

You should use load function to load external data to your model(use **eager loading**):

```
$menu=Menu::find(1);
$menu->load('dailyMeals','dailyMeals.meals');
```

**Note** : For **hide pivot object in response** add this code to your menu model:

```
protected $hidden = ['pivot'];
```

**Note** : You should have `dailyMeals` in your `menu` model and `meals` relation in your `dailyMeals` model

For more information You can Visit [Laravel Document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).